# QML/C++ getting info from QML in main.cpp

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to get info from a new type -Cloud- instantiated in the example.qml from my main.cpp.
I have no error of compilation neither of execution. I have only my empty object cloud.

Here my cloud.h

```
#ifndef CLOUD_H
#define CLOUD_H

#include <QtQuick/QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QColor>


class Cloud: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName)
    Q_PROPERTY(QColor color READ color WRITE setColor)
public:
    Cloud(QObject *parent=0);

    QString name() const;
    void setName(const QString &name);

    QColor color() const;
    void setColor(const QColor &color);


private:
    QString m_name;
    QColor m_color;
};

#endif
```

Here my cloud.cpp

```
#include "cloud.h"
#include <QPainter>

Cloud::Cloud(QObject *parent)
    :QObject(parent)
{
}
QString Cloud::name() const{
     return m_name;
}
void Cloud::setName(const QString &name)
{
    m_name = name;
}
QColor Cloud::color() const
{
     return m_color;
}
void Cloud::setColor(const QColor &color)
{
    m_color = color;
}
```

Here my main.cpp

```
#include "cloud.h"

#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Cloud>("Sky", 1,0,"Cloud");


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/example.qml")));
    QQmlComponent component(&engine,    QUrl((QStringLiteral("qrc:/example.qml"))));
    Cloud *cloud = qobject_cast<Cloud*>(component.create());

    if(cloud){
        qWarning() << "The cloud is "<< cloud->name();
    }else{
        qWarning() << "there is no cloud" <<cloud;
    }

    return app.exec();
}
```

And finally, here my example.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Sky 1.0

Item {
    width: 300
    height: 200
    Item{
        Cloud{
            id:aCloud
            name: "Cumulus"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to solve my problem following those tutorials :
[Defining QML types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-definetypes.html)
[Extending QML example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-tutorials-extending-qml-example.html)

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Does it crash on `Cloud *cloud = qobject_cast<Cloud*>(component.create());` ?

Comment: No, it doesn't crash it just return an OBject(0x0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `component.create();` you are creating an `Item` which has `Cloud` as a child. If you want to get Cloud you should do something like:

```
QObject* myObject = component.create();
QQuickItem* item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(myObject);
Cloud *cloud = item->findchild<Cloud*>();
```

EDITED: Updated with coyotte508 remarks.

Comment: That you for your response, but it doesn't work. I have an error "Invalid propery name" on objectname in the example.qml

Comment: @Cam the answer is correct, but forget about the `objectName`, just do `Cloud *cloud = item->findchild<Cloud*>("aCloud");` as `aCloud` is the id of the `Cloud` object. Check out [this doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild). Actually you don't even need to specify the name if there's only one `Cloud` child, so `Cloud *cloud = item->findchild<Cloud*>();` suffices.

Comment: Sorry I made a error on the syntax. Now I have an error "C2783 could not deduce template argument"

Comment: @Coyotte508, I've tried your solution, I don't have any compilation or execution errors, but my object is still empty QObject(0*0)  `QObject *myObject = component.create();
    QQuickItem *item = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(myObject);
    Cloud *cloud = item->findChild<Cloud*>("aCloud");`

Comment: @Cam, how is your `main.qml`? Those work for me: http://pastebin.com/4qQh51z1 <- main.cpp, http://pastebin.com/zMcKiGFd <- main.qml, and the same example.qml and other files.

Comment: @Coyotte508 I just found that the only difference between our code was the `QGuiApplication` on your code and `QApplication` in mine. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Coyotte508 and perencia I succedded to find what was wrong :
in my main.cpp I had a `QApplication` instead of a `QGuiApplication`